# User has access to tables but cannot see it under schema

Tags: mysql

[image: Picture of Problem]

I have created a user, Sales_Person, that is only allowed access to two tables. When I open the connection, using SELECT*FROM works on the tables I need it to, but the user cannot see said tables under the database when I click the arrow to expand it.

```
CREATE USER  IF NOT EXISTS Sales_Person@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '123';
GRANT SELECT ON final_project.payment TO Sales_Person@localhost;
GRANT SELECT ON final_project.invoice TO Sales_Person@localhost;
```

Answer (score 0):

After the grantor grant privileges, execute `flush privileges;` . Then log in MySQL using the said user and make sure the `user@host` name is exactly Sales_Person@localhost by using `select user();` . Next, run `show grants;` to verify its privileges. If nothing is wrong, run `select * from final_project.payment;` . If the result set is displayed accordingly but the table remains hidden under schema, try hitting the `refresh all` option .
Well, as I'm not able to see the image due to some internet regulations, I just took a guess that it happened in workbench.